# Unable to locate englishSR.ser.gz in Stanford coreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I downloaded `stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20.zip` and `stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20.zip` but in neither of them i couldnot locate `englishSR.ser.gz` ( supposed to be located at `edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz`) .

Is there something wrong i am doing ?

Answer (score 6):

That file is in the shift reduce parsers jar, which you can find on this page: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Just look for "shift reduce parser models".

The file for v 3.5 and beyond is called: stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar.